# How can I view console output of a program in an editor like emacs or Vim in linux?

Tags: linux, emacs, console, vi

Lets say I have a simple  program :
(pseudocode)

```
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
   print(i + "\n");
   sleep(1);
}


Output:
0
1
2
```

Is there way to view this output in an editor like emacs or Vi as it changes ?
The behaviour I want is like "tail -f" done on a file being continously written to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In emacs at least, you can open a terminal window and have it at one side. Try <kbd>M-x</kbd>ansi-term<kbd>RET</kbd>. Then you can divide the screen, using the different <kbd>C-x</kbd><number>.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually built in to emacs :)

```
M-x auto-revert-tail-mode
```

From C-h f auto-revert-tail-mode :

> When Tail mode is enabled, the tail of the file is constantly
>   followed, as with the shell command `tail -f'.  This means that
>   whenever the file grows on disk (presumably because some
>   background process is appending to it from time to time), this is
>   reflected in the current buffer.

Answer (score 2):

```
          (start-process "my-process" "foo" "ls" "-l" "/user/lewis/bin")
               ⇒ #<process my-process<1>>

          ---------- Buffer: foo ----------
          total 2
          lrwxrwxrwx  1 lewis     14 Jul 22 10:12 gnuemacs --> /emacs
          -rwxrwxrwx  1 lewis     19 Jul 30 21:02 lemon

          Process my-process<1> finished

          Process my-process finished
          ---------- Buffer: foo ----------
```

Comment: Please explain this more, it would help.

Comment: this will start an async process whose output will be appended to the given buffer. if you want to programatically interact with a process this is the way to go, if you just want to run commands use m-x term or shell

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs, there is M-x shell-command, as well as various specialized modes for monitoring the output from a command. You can also run a shell inside Emacs with M-x shell. It is also not hard to have a process produce output directly into an Emacs buffer from elisp; see the documentation for start-process (C-h f start-process RET).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to the following using "ansi-term" and your own program (which you would substitute in place of the "top" process used in my example):

```
(progn 
  (ansi-term "/bin/sh" "top")
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (insert "top")
  (term-send-input))
```